# How to stop text from filling the "empty" spot?

Tags: floats

How do I stop my figures from being pushed into an "open" spot, and having text fill the "empty" spot? The paper does not have a very clear flow because while one paragraph is talking about Figure 1, Figure 1 is actually **AFTER** the paragraph that is talking about Figure 2. I have tried changing the `\begin{figure}[!ht]` but it has not solved my problem.

I'm basically looking for a way just to put empty spaces and order the document how my Source is typed.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Flee.jpeg}
\caption{Whether the victim was fleeing}
\label{fig:complete}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Threat.jpeg}
\caption{Whether the victim was a threat }
\label{instruct}
\end{minipage} 
\end{figure}
```

Here are my packages

```
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}% To incorporate .eps illustrations using PDFLaTeX, etc.
\usepackage{subfigure}% Support for small, `sub' figures and tables
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,merge]{natbib}% Citation support using natbib.sty
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage[labelsep=:]{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There should be a figure environment in each of the minipages. Other method: using the `floatrow` package.

Comment: Do you have something like `\flushbottom` active? What document class are you using?

Comment: @Bernard a figure environment should *never* be inside a minipage.

Comment: So the O.P. should use `\captionof{figure}{...}`?

Comment: Does the paragraph that contains a call-out to Figure 1 happen to occur close to the bottom of a page?

Comment: @Mico Yes, it is fairly close to the bottom of the page, so it auto inserts the next paragraph, but I don't want that to happen.

Comment: @Werner I edited the post to include the packages I have. Everything should be included now.

Comment: Your code includes the snippet `\begin{figure}[!ht]`. Basically, what this means is if the entire `figure` does *not* fit right where the directive is encountered (the "h" part), the only other placement option you're giving it is "t", for top of the next page. What, then, do you want to happen if the `figure` doesn't fit where the `\begin{figure}` is encountered? I can think of only two remaining options: Create a (potentially massively) overfull page, or create a big blob of whitespace toward the bottom of the page. Neither option seems attractive, does it?]

Comment: @CynicalF: ...everything except the `\documentclass` and something that replicates the problem. We don't have `Flee.jpg` and `Threat.jpg`. Ideally we want an MWE. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: @Mico I would like the massive blob of whitespace, if you could tell me how that would be done? My figures are mostly quite small, so it wouldn't be that large of a whitespace, but for my sanity, and the reader's sanity, I think chronological order works best in this instance. Otherwise, the reader reads about Figure 1 and Figure 2, which are two separate paragraphs, before even seeing Figure 1.

Comment: Just look at all the questions about removing a massive blob of white space around figures.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I want to ADD the massive blob of white space though?

Comment: So copy the problem, not the answer.  Seriously, all you need is to put the "figure" in a minipage with \captionof{figure}{...} or use the figure [H] option from the float package.  You can use \vspace*{\fill} to control where the massive blob appears.

Comment: note the _only_ reason to use a `figure` environment is to take the content out of the document flow and mark it as a float that can be inserted elsewhere to help with page breaking, you have restricted the places it can be re-inserted so make it more likely to float to the end. An image that is part of the text can be directly inserted with `\includegraphics`